# Knockout KoGrid - no data displayed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kogrid

I have an ASP.Net MVC5 app into which I have added a couple of views that use the excellent KnockoutJs KoGrid (http://knockout-contrib.github.io/KoGrid/#/examples). My problem is I have created a third view that uses the KoGrid and despite following the pattern used on the other views I cannot convince KoGrid to display the data. I have created a plnkr for the problem here:http://plnkr.co/edit/0OaqD2?p=preview.

The "real" view has a couple of tabs, the first to display database details, the second *should* display Workflow Rules in a ko grid. Here's the view model I return from the controller:

```
public class AdminViewModel
{
    public DatabaseDetails DatabaseDetails { get; set; }
    public List<WorkflowRule> WorkflowRules { get; set; }
}

public class WorkflowRule 
{
    public int WorkflowRuleId { get; set; }
    public string ReceivePortName { get; set; }
    public string MessageType { get; set; }
    public string TriggerSource { get; set; }
    public string TargetEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public int AssignedToId { get; set; }
    public string AssignedToName { get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseDetails
{...
```

My knockout vm is as follows (I have removed boilerplate paging code to keep more concise):

```
function ViewModel(vm) {
var self = this;
this.workflowRules = ko.observableArray(vm.WorkflowRules);


this.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var data;
        if (searchText) {
            var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
            $.getJSON('/Admin/GetDataPage', { tabName: "WorkflowRules", pageSize: pageSize }, function (returnedPayload) {
                data = returnedPayload.filter(function (item) {
                    return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                });
                self.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize);
            });          
        } else {
            $.getJSON('/Admin/GetDataPage', { tabName: "WorkflowRules", pageSize: pageSize }, function (returnedPayload) {
                self.setPagingData(returnedPayload, page, pageSize);
            });
        }
    }, 100);
};


this.gridOptions = {
    afterSelectionChange: function () { return true; },
    data: self.workflowRules,
    enablePaging: true,
    pagingOptions: self.pagingOptions,
    filterOptions: self.filterOptions,
    selectWithCheckboxOnly: true,
    selectedItems: self.selected,
    canSelectRows: true,
    displaySelectionCheckbox: true,
    columnDefs: [{ field: 'ReceivePortName', displayName: 'Receive Port', width: 130 },
                { field: 'MessageType', displayName: 'Message Type', width: 200 },
                { field: 'TriggerSource', displayName: 'Source', width: 60 },
                { field: 'TargetEmailAddress', displayName: 'Email', width: 130 },
                { field: 'AssignedToName', displayName: 'Assigned To', width: 140 },
    ]
};
```

};

The key parts of my view are as follows:

```
    @model TVS.ESB.BamPortal.Website.Models.AdminViewModel
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@{  string data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model); }

<div class="tab-pane" id="WorkflowRules">
                <h4>Workflow Rules</h4>
                <div id="KoGrid" data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions"></div>
            </div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/KnockoutVM/WorkflowRules.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/KoGrid.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var vm = new ViewModel(@Html.Raw(data));
        ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("KoGrid"));
    </script>
}
```

Here's a screen grab of how Chrome displays the view:

[image]

Could anyone please tell me where I've gone wrong - why no data is displayed in the grid?

I've just realised that if I reduce the size of the browser displaying the kogrid then the data appears. I've made a short video of this here: http://biztalkers.com/video/kogridproblem.mp4

Comment: I've added some of the missing resources in your plnkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZZ2QZw4ZqfIOVFX7vTBc?p=preview Could you explain what's wrong using this example?

Comment: Your plnk with the scripts added works great but I already have those scripts added in my solution but I don't get the KoGrid displayed. Actually I do get to see the drop-down arrow - please see screen grab that I've added to the question

Comment: Does Chrome's Developer Tools console log any errors?

Comment: No errors I'm afraid. I can see that the data fro the grid makes it's way to Chrome also.

Comment: I just noticed that if I reduce the size of the browser window displaying the kogrid then the grid data appears. I've made a short screencast of this here: http://biztalkers.com/video/kogridproblem.mp4

Comment: So I guess this must be a CSS issue, I will keep looking

Comment: getting exact view, out of 240 rows, grid is displaying only 8. after resizing the browser all 240 renders, no errors. how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work-around this CSS problem by setting my "Workflow Rules" tab as the default.

Later, on a different website - I found the same behaviour if only one row of data was returned from the controller. Where two or more rows were returned then they displayed correctly.